# SQL query not returning the value it should, however it works when putting the method in a different class

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

For those who have read and answered on my post yesterday, we are one step closer to a solution. After debugging for quite a while, I've located the problem to be either a faulty constructor or an ignored return with the valid object.

```
public Speler geefSpeler(String username) {
    Speler speler = null;
    String password;
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Connectie.JDBC_URL);
            PreparedStatement query = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Speler WHERE username =?")) {

        query.setString(1, username);

        try (ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery();) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                password = rs.getString(2);

                int[] aantal = intArrayListToArray(geefAantalGewonnen(username));
//geefAantalGewonnen() is a method that return an arraylist of ints, which gets turned into an array using intArrayListToArray()
                speler = new Speler(username, password, aantal);//Constructor added below
                return speler;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("An error occured.");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    return speler;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> geefAantalGewonnen(String username) {
    ArrayList<Integer> aantal = new ArrayList();
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Connectie.JDBC_URL); // Volgorde bij historiek steken, komt overeen met naam
            PreparedStatement query = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT aantalGewonnen From Historiek WHERE username= ? ORDER BY volgorde")) {                                                                                                                   //Several entries with 1 column in common (username). Selects these values.
        query.setString(1, username);
        try (ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery();) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                int aantalPerGraad = rs.getInt(1);
                aantal.add(aantalPerGraad);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("An issue occured");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }

    return aantal;
}

//This turns the arraylist returned by the previous method into an array

public int[] intArrayListNaarArray(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    int[] array = new int[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        array[i] = list.get(i);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Constructor for the class Speler:

```
public Speler(String username, String password, int[] aantalGewonnen) {
    setUsername(username);
    setPassword(password);
    setAantalGewonnen(aantalGewonnen);
}
private void setAantalGewonnen(int[] aantalGewonnen) {
    if (aantalGewonnen.length == mapper.geefAantalMoeilijkheidsgraden())
    this.aantalGewonnen = aantalGewonnen;
}
```

The other setters have been heavily tested before and aren't the cause of the problem. The one I did provide was added recently and might be the cause of the problem.

I've input a username and password that I checked are valid. Removing the all-catcher from the inner try in the first method results in a `NullPointerException` being thrown in the setter. Running this exact method in a different class (albeit made static to run it in main method) returns the int it should return. 
`Connection` class is fine as previous queries worked fine.

Debugging has shown that it runs fine until `speler = new Speler(username, password, aantal);`, after which is skips the `return speler;` due to the `NullPointerException` being throwns.

My question to you: what causes this problem? All methods I thought were relevant, should I have missed any, please notify me in a comment (and please don't be too harsh on my reputation, I'm only a lowly java novice).

Comment: For me it looks odd that you start a new query while handling the result set for the first and also that you never call close() on your statements. I would read the password and then close the first statement before calling geefAantalGewonnen. Also, I would suggest making both the methods static.

Comment: That might very well be the issue. I haven't used a query inside another query before the problems started.